# UITextView with "Done" button *and* "Return" key?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, uitextview

I use a UITextView for multiline text entry in my iPhone app, and I have set the "Return" key to display "Done." I've also set up the return key to disable first responder status, so that hitting "done" actually exits the UITextView. However, I also want to enable users to be able to enter multiline text into the UITextView, i.e. to be able to use the "Return" key. Is there any way to make this work on the iPhone/iPad's UI?

Comment: A separate 'Done' button as a top right bar button would make it less confusing to me; changing function of 'Return' key is not normal (expected) behavior in a UITextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be time consuming but you could create your own keyboard with both these keys (this can be done by specifiying the `Input View` for the `UITextView` ).

Another alternative could be having a button that sits just above the keyboard that would dismiss the keyboard. You can use the `UITextView`'s `Input Accessory View` which allows you to create a view that sits on top of the keyboard. [See here for more information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) (I'm aware this document is for iPad but it works for all iOS devices - also just to note, both these require iOS 3.2 or greater).

This should only need to be done on the iphone because the iPad keyboard already comes with a [dismiss keyboard button as well as a return button.](http://daringfireball.net/misc/2010/04/ipad-keyboard-abc)

Comment: This is very interesting & I'll have to try it out. Also, in your last paragraph, you mean that this should only need to be done on the *iPhone* because the iPad keyboard already has the dismiss keyboard button, right? Thanks!

Comment: I just realised the link actually is incorrect, it auto-directs you to a different page, I've editted the link so it's the correct link. Hope you managed to sort this out!

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this issue for 5 years waiting for apple to wake up and create some sort of solution for the textfield multiline responding to done button until I decided to create one myself.
there you go:[UITextField multiline with hide keyboard option](http://code.google.com/p/galtextfield/)