# How to add a done button over the pickerview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitextview, uipickerview

I want to display a **picker view and a done button** above the picker view . 
        
 I have a custom label which will become first responder . So when it becomes first responder I am displaying a picker view as the input view for my label. 
         Now I want to have a done button on the picker to dismiss the picker view. I played with the **inputAccesoryView** property of **UIPickerView** but did not succeed . inputAccessoryView is possible with **UITextView** , not sure about the **UIPickerView** . Here is the link for how it can be done with **UITextView**

[UITextView with “Done” button *and* “Return” key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203323/uitextview-with-done-button-and-return-key)

Has any body tried this , if someone knows how to do this for picker , please answer.

Thank you all in advance !!

Comment: A custom label which becomes first responder? Do you mean a textfield?

Comment: Is your view in a nib or in the code?

Comment: @Nick Weaver , I have created a subclass of UILabel to implement the first responder thing

Answer (score 3):

Add your picker view to an action sheet. First of all make sure youre view controller impliments UIPickerViewDelegate and UIActionSheetDelegate.

Then add this method, and call it when you want to show your picker.

```
- (void)showPicker {    
    UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pick Value"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,180,0,0)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    

    [menu addSubview:pickerView];
    [menu showInView:self.view.superview];

    //Change the height value in your CGRect to change the size of the actinsheet
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 615)];

    [pickerView release]; 
    [menu release]; 
}
```

Comment: yes that's the idea ,it shud work. The above link mentioned by Jhaliya gives the complete solution.

Comment: This is against Apples policy.

Comment: Chris it may well be but that has nothing to do with the question above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to put the picker inside a view with a 'Done' button and present that view

Comment: Yes but that would be more complicated rather the link provide above by Jhaliya explains a simpler way . . . Thanks